# C++ Writing to a CSV file

Tags: c++, csv

The purpose of the code is to prompt the user to enter how many connections/nets & write to a CSV file.

The code runs and writes to the CSV file on the first column but after the user is prompted
to input the # of nets again, it writes on the same column instead of the next one which has the header
"Connector 2" or Column B.

**How do I get my code to write to the first column, move on to the next column and prompt the user to
input the # of nets/connections?**

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int nets;

ofstream myFile;
myFile.open("My File.csv"); // Create file

myFile << "Connector 1" << "," << "Connector 2" << endl; // Headers

 while (true) {

    cout << "# of Nets: " << endl;
    cin >> nets;

    if (nets > 0) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= nets; i++) {

            myFile << i << endl;
            myFile << ",";
        
        }
    }

    else {

        break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to move on to the next record, don't use `endl` in your loop.

Comment: Actually, don't use `endl` at all unless you explicitly want to flush the stream while writing a newline.  Develop the habit of using `'\n'` instead.

Comment: You want to check `if (!myFile.open()) { /* handle error */ }` before you attempt to write to it. Why you don't want `std::endl`, see [C++: “std::endl” vs “\n”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

Comment: Why not `for (int i = 0; i < nets; i++) { std::cout << "enter conn1 conn2: "; if (std::cin >> conn1 >> conn2) myFile << conn1 << "," << conn2 << '\n';`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you want to write the data **column by column** while the CSV format reads them **row by row**. One way to make your program work is to store the data until the user is done, and then store it row by row. Ex :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int nets;
    vector<int> netsList; // Will be used to save the numbers until the user is done
    int maxValue = -1; // The biggest value entered by the user, you could also look in the vector for this value

    ofstream myFile;
    myFile.open("My File.csv"); // Create file

    myFile << "Connector 1" << "," << "Connector 2" << endl; // Headers

    while (true) {

        cout << "# of Nets: " << endl;
        cin >> nets;

        if (nets > 0) {

            netsList.push_back(nets); // Save the number for later
            if (nets > maxValue) // Update the maximum value
                maxValue = nets;
        }
        else {

            // Now write to the file, you could open the file now if you wanted
            for (int i = 1; i <= maxValue; i++) // Loop until the biggest value is reached (these will be rows)
            {
                for (auto num : netsList) // Loop all the elements in the vector (columns)
                {
                    if (num >= i) // If the value entered is greater or equal to the current i (row) value
                        myFile << i << ","; // Write the number
                    else
                        myFile << " " << ","; // Write an empty case
                }
                myFile << "\n";
            }

            myFile.close(); // Close the file
            break; // Now quit
        }
    }
}
```